# Trying to avoid anonymous functions in express routes without callback hell

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I am trying to cleanup my node app using express and mongodb to make it more readable. I am trying to avoid using anonymous callback functions and give them names to make it more readable.

I have a route which makes a database call, then renders a page

Original working code

```
app.get('/updatebeer', function(req, res, next){
    var query = {'_id':req.query.id};
    Brew.find(query, function(err, result){
        if(err) 
            return next(err);
        if(result.length===1) 
            res.render('updatebeer', {brew: result[0]});
    });

});
```

I can use a function name for the first callback without problems

```
function updateBeer(req, res, next){
    var query = {'_id':req.query.id};
    Brew.find(query, function(err, result){
        if(err) 
            return next(err);
        if(result.length===1) 
            res.render('updatebeer', {brew: result[0]});
    });
}

app.get('/updatebeer', updateBeer);
```

But if I try to remove the anonymous function in the Mongo query

```
function updateBeer(req, res, next){
    var query = {'_id':req.query.id};
    Brew.find(query, renderBeer);
}

function renderBeer(err, result){
    if(err) 
        return next(err);
    if(result.length===1) 
        res.render('updatebeer', {brew: result[0]});
}

app.get('/updatebeer', updateBeer);
```

I get an error that res is not defined, I kind of understand the problem but I am not sure the best way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't exactly solve your problem, but using the Promise syntax might help clean your functions slightly.  With the Mongo node driver, if you omit the callback, Mongo will give you back a Promise which you can `then`.

```
function updateBeer(req, res, next) {
    var query = {
        '_id': req.query.id
    };
    Brew
        .find(query)
        .then((result) => {
            if (result.length === 1)
                res.render('updatebeer', {
                    brew: result[0]
                });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            return next(err);
        });
}

app.get('/updatebeer', updateBeer);
```

Your problem with your below code, is that, as node tells you, `res` is defined in `updateBeer`, but not `renderBeer`:

```
function updateBeer(req, res, next){
    var query = {'_id':req.query.id};
    Brew.find(query, renderBeer);
}

function renderBeer(err, result){
    if(err) 
        return next(err); // There is no "next" in this scope
    if(result.length===1) 
        res.render('updatebeer', {brew: result[0]});  // There is no "res" in this scope either
}

app.get('/updatebeer', updateBeer);
```

---

I would even go so far as to suggest breaking your program up into a sort of MVC structure where all Beer related stuff is relegated to a Beer Model, and your route oriented Beer things are in your Beer Controller.  You kind of already have Beer View stuff sectioned to a Beer View since you `res.render("updatebeer")`.

### Terse Beer "Model"

```
function beerTransformer(beerResult) {
    if (beerResult.length !== 1) {
        throw new Error("THERE'S NO BEER!!!");
    }
    return Promise.resolve(beerResult[0]);
}
```

### Beer Controller

```
function updateBeer(req, res, next) {
    var query = {
        '_id': req.query.id
    };
    Brew
        .find(query)
        .then(beerTransformer)
        .then((beer) => {
            // Very thin, delegates all beer related things to the model
            return res.render("updatebeer", {
                brew: beer
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            return next(err);
        });
}

app.get('/updatebeer', updateBeer);
```

Comment: This is a decent approach (excellent given the quesiton asked ) .  That said: I find the code to be easier to understand if every bit has  a specfic function.  Here data access and business logic (the transform) is embedded in the route-handler.  I would be inclined to leave the route handler to be reponsible for the request and response and not any logic assiciated with the feature at hand. I suspect the original quesiton isn't asked if they are working in defined layers...

Comment: @akaphenom Agreed, the router should be ignorant that there even is a DB back end.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I didn't intend to call you and your answer out, but merely to provide insight to the original poster about better coding style.  One of the side-effects of stack is we often provide explicit answers to questions that wouldn't have been asked if the code had been properly organized, and the answer almost encourages the pattern.  Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

I have my app working in a "hacky" way and wanted to apply some better coding practices to make it more maintainable and readable. 

I wanted to start with named functions, and then look into other aproaches like promises but I think they're much easier.